# Failed to copy /home/[...]/ecj.jar to /usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar due to java.io.FileNotFoundException /usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar (Permission denied)

Tags: ant, liferay

While `ant clean` works fine within Liferay IDE, when trying from command line I get:

```
$ ant clean
Buildfile: /home/nico/myportlet/build.xml
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /usr/share/ant/lib
Attempt to copy /home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/lib/ecj.jar to /usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar using NIO Channels failed due to '/usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar (Permission denied)'.  Falling back to streams.

BUILD FAILED
/home/nico/myportlet/build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/portlets/build-common-portlet.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/build-common-plugin.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/build-common.xml:94: Failed to copy /home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/lib/ecj.jar to /usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar due to java.io.FileNotFoundException /usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar (Permission denied)

Total time: 2 seconds
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the file manually as root.

After you have done that, ant will be happy and execute the tasks without complaining.

Here is how to do on Linux/Mac:

```
sudo cp /home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/lib/ecj.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/
```

Answer (score 2):

Or to not messing up with system libraries we could reference folder to ant like :

```
ant clean -lib /home/nico/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp14/lib
```